# Pass and View Dictionary from view to template in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates, django-views

I am passing the dictionary to the view but it is now showing on the page.
i also have print the dictionary on the before passing, and it prints the whole dictionary on the screen perfectly. but when i pass it to the html page, it does not show at all..

**view.py**

```
def show_log_messages(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    log_dictionary = {}
    count = 0
    e = log_messages.objects.filter(log_status='Queue').values('sent_to', 'unique_arguments')
    count = 0
    logs = {}
    for d in e:
        count +=1
        new_dict = {'email': d["sent_to"], 'log_id': d["unique_arguments"]}
        logs[count] = new_dict

    for keys in logs:
        print logs[keys]['log_id']
        print logs[keys]['email']


    return render_to_response('show_logs.html', logs, context)
```

**show_logs.html**

```
{% if logs %}
        <ul>
            {% for log in logs:  %}
                {% for keys in log  %}
            <li>{{ log[keys]['email'] }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <strong>There are no logs present.</strong>
    {% endif %}
```

it only show the heading not the list element.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is very unpythonic and undjango.  You should pass to template a list instead of dictionary.

Also `shortcuts.render` is much simpler to use than `render_to_response`.

```
def show_log_messages(request):
    messages = log_messages.objects.filter(log_status='Queue') \
                                   .values('sent_to', 'unique_arguments')
    logs = [{'email': msg['sent_to'], 'log_id': msg['unique_arguments']}
                       for msg in messages]    
    return render(request, 'show_logs.html', {'logs': logs})
```

Template:

```
{% if logs %}
    <ul>
        {% for log in logs %}
            <li>{{ log.email }} - {{ log.log_id }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <strong>There are no logs present.</strong>
{% endif %}
```

BTW, `logs` list is unnecessary here. You can pass `messages` queryset directly into template and show `{{ log.sent_to }}` and `{{ log.unique_arguments }}` in the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The `render_to_response` shortcut takes a dictionary. If you want to access `logs` in the template, it should be in that dictionary:

```
return render_to_response("show_logs.html", {'logs': logs}, context)
```

The second problem is that your django template is invalid. It looks like you're trying to write Python in the template. You'd probably find it helpful to read through the [Django template language docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/).

It's not clear to me what you're trying to display, so here's an example of looping through each log, and displaying its id and email. You should be able to adjust this to get the result you want.

```
{% if logs %}
    {% for key, value in logs.items  %}
        {{ key }}, {{ key.log_id}}, {{ key.email }}
    {% endf
{% else %}
    <strong>There are no logs present.</strong>
{% endif %}
```