# How to print pretty JSON on a html page from a django template?

Tags: python, json, django

Why is it that in python, I can pretty print JSON with the python example below, but in a django template, it doesn't work? How can I pretty print JSON in a django template?

python:

```
import requests, json
url = 'https://api.example.com/details'
r = requests.get(url)
json_data = r.json()
json_pretty = json.dumps(json_data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print (json_pretty)
```

django views.py:

```
def json_list(request):
    url = 'https://api.example.com/details'
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_data = r.json()
    json_pretty = json.dumps(json_data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    context = {
        "json_pretty": json_pretty,
        }
    return render(request, "json_output.html", context)
```

template:

```
<div>{{ json_pretty }}</div>
```

Comment: Can you please check this link ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861078/pass-and-view-dictionary-from-view-to-template-in-django

Comment: Can you try without json.dumps. because json.dumps convert dict data to string.

Comment: Use `<pre>` instead of `<div>`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just want to keep your indent, You can use

```
return HttpResponse(json_pretty,content_type="application/json")
```

If it is a must to use django template, you can use the HTML `<pre>` tag as suggested by  Klaus.
So your template becomes

```
<pre>{{ json_pretty }}</pre>
```

Comment: I added the safe filter to convert the string to html <pre>{{ json_pretty | safe }}</pre>

Answer (score 28):

Why not just use the [`pprint` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#pprint)?

## view

`context["my_json"] = {i: i for i in range(100)}`

## template

```
<pre>{{ my_json }}</pre>
vs    
<pre>{{ my_json | pprint }}</pre>
```

## Screnshot

[image]

Or if you want something even better, create a custom filter

### `templatetags/extras.py`

```
import json

from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def pretty_json(value):
    return json.dumps(value, indent=4)
```

## template

```
{% load extras %}
<pre>{{ my_json | pretty_json }}</pre>
```

Comment: the solution '''<pre>{{ my_json }}</pre>
vs    
<pre>{{ my_json | pprint }}</pre>'''   - worked fine

Comment: @AmanGupta For me, the stored JSON was all on one line, so <pre> also displays it all on one line, whereas pprint does the right thing with line breaks.

Comment: @shacker  then use pprint

Comment: A little reminder, you can re-run runserver after creating template tags if it's show error extras not registered

Answer (score 4):

I had to use a combination of answers to get what I needed. The missing thing I needed was the filter `linebreaks`

So in my views.py I have a function

```
def foobar(request, test_id):
    json_response = json.dumps(example_dict, indent=3)
    return render(request, 'foo/bar.html', {"json_string": json_response})
```

and in my django template

```
<pre>{{ json_response | linebreaks }}</pre>
```

My json string had a bunch of `\n` in it so this made it look nice by removing those (might be caused by mongoengine objects)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't pretty up is because it renders to HTML, which handles spacing different depending on the tags you put it in. Your best bet would be to use a syntax highlighting library. They are usually simple to set up. There are many of them, like [highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js), [prism](http://prismjs.com/) and many, many more.

I forgot to mention the Pythonic library for syntax highlighting, [Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/)!